# Reversing sort order of ingested RSS feed in PHP

Tags: wordpress

I have a site where I am 'pulling' local events from a secondary website RSS feed. I have this working however the feed is displaying in reverse order with the local events dated later (i.e. at the end of October versus events dated for today) showing up at the top instead of the bottom.

Here is the code I am using for the feed ingest:

```
<?php if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {

include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php'); // include the required file
$feed = fetch_feed('http://sample.com.au/events/feed/');  // specify the source feed

$limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(25); // specify number of items
$semti = array_flip($limit);
$items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); // create an array of items

}
if ($limit == 0) echo '<div>The feed is unavailable.</div>';
else foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

<p><b><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank">
<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a></b>
<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_date('| j F | g:i a') ); ?><br>
<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $item->get_content() ); ?>
</p>  

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works perfectly to get my  remote RSS feed and display the title, date of the event and the excerpt, however the order is reverse sorted.

I tried adding filters like "sort and ksort" in the "foreach ($items $items) :" area but this did not work for me. I've racked my brains on this one and am hoping someone can help me out. I appreciate any guidance/help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the appropriately named `array_reverse` function!

```
<?php if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {

    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php'); // include the required file
    $feed = fetch_feed('http://sample.com.au/events/feed/');  // specify the source feed

    $limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(25); // specify number of items
    $items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); // create an array of items 
    $semti = array_reverse($items); // & flip it

}
if ($limit == 0) echo '<div>The feed is unavailable.</div>';
else foreach ($semti as $item) : ?>

    <p><b><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a></b>
    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_date('| j F | g:i a') ); ?><br>
    <?php echo sanitize_text_field( $item->get_content() ); ?>
</p>  

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[From PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

> #### array_reverse
>
> Return an array with elements in reverse order
>
> `array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )`
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array with the order of the elements reversed.

Comment: Cameron. Where have you been all my life? That is genius and so simple too, thank you very much that fixed it perfectly!

Comment: No problem amigo! Glad I could help.